# iOS 8 UINavigationController disable Back Button

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uinavigationbar

in my Navigation Controller I need to temporarily disable the back button. I know that it can be hidden using the following or something similar:

`[self.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];`

But that is not what I need, instead I want the back button to be greyed out and non-responsive to user touch events. Is their a way to achieve this without replacing the default back button?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 20):

To disable the back button, these commands would make it do what you want it to do:

**Enable:**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

**Disabled:**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

Update:

As of iOS 7, there's also a swipe that you'll want to disable on the `UINavigationBar`.

```
// You wrap it an 'if' statement so it doesn't crash
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
// disable the interactivePopGestureRecognizer
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

Comment: There's also a swipe that you might "bump into".  I updated how to disable it.

Comment: This disables all buttons, not just the back button.

Answer (score 14):

This hides the back button, so it becomes unreachable for the user. And it disables the swipe gesture.

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

Swift:

```
navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

See more info in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624934-sethidesbackbutton).

Comment: Simpler than @adrian

Comment: The proper way to do it. This also disables the swipe recogniser.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is quite old but I had this problem too.

In my case in one scenario I had to disable the back button and in another one I had to disable all navigation buttons. my solution was disabling the navigation bar in total in both scenarios:

```
self.navigationController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

This won't show the buttons as disabled but will prevent touches.

Hope this will help

Comment: I think this actually disables interaction for the whole of the view of the top view controller...!

Comment: +1 My use case was disabling the back button while showing a progres bar and awaiting a network response so this answer was perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that following should help:

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry guys, my belief didn't come true.

It seems that property `backBarButtonItem` is designed only for setting custom title or image for Back Button.

From documentation:

> If you want to specify a custom image or title for the back button,
>   you can assign a custom bar button item (with your custom title or
>   image) to this property instead. When configuring your bar button
>   item, do not assign a custom view to it; the navigation item ignores
>   custom views in the back bar button anyway.
>
> The default value of this property is nil.

Unfortunately I didn't find any way of disabling back button with saving its native look and behaviour, because any time when I try to set custom `UIBarButtonItem` into `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` property - it gets updated with appropriate native back button style and it always has `enabled == YES`.

I think this is done by Apple for a reason because we basically shouldn't force the user to stay on a detail screen and disable him from going back.
Also, in iOS7 and later user always can use swipe-from-left-edge gesture (if you don't disable it) to go back.

The only one ugly thing that I can recommend is to create a custom `UIBarButtonItem` and set it into `leftBarButtonItem` with 'Back' title, target and selector which will pop your viewController. By default it will substitute native back button.
Then you can disable it as usual using `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO`.

Unfortunately it will not look and act (in case of title updating depending on available space) as native back button :(

Comment: That is not working. I tried calling your code in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear and in both cases it doesn't seem to have any effect at all.

Comment: @user3636891 I concur that this code is not working for me either

Answer (score 0):

Just set a disabled back button on the navigation item of the previous view controller. Don't try to disable your custom back button if you already had one, won't work. Just set a new one which is disabled. You can reach the previous navigation item through the `UINavigationBar.backItem` property.

```
// set disabled back button
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
backButton.isEnabled = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton

// disable pop gesture
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```